# Best way to add .mmmodel file to my xcode9 project?

Tags: ios, machine-learning, swift4, xcode9-beta

In my app, I want to add a Machine learning model like Inceptionv3.

How to add Inceptionv3.mmmodel to my project?

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean an mlmodel-file? If not, you can use the [coremltools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coremltools) provided by apple to convert your model into a mlmodel file.

If you have your .mlmodel file, you can drag it your Xcode project and enable the target membership for the file in your project.

Xcode will then automatically generate an interface with which you can interact with your model. The name of the generated interface will then be shown.

You can then instantiate your model class and use its `prediction(...)` method to perform your machine learning task.

This process is shown in every detail in [Introduction to CoreML](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/703/) from this years WWDC (the actual implementation starts at minute 22)